# How to send my machine information to an Android application using Java

Tags: java, android

I want to create a Java stand alone application to send my machine information like Operating System, Processor, Installed Memory (RAM), System Type etc. to an Android application via USB cable. 
Can I have the best possible way/technique to do this.

Comment: You can use sockets to send the info. Moreover post the code what you have done till now

Comment: No I didn't start till now, I need some idea then only I can start.